# installing guile, issue with libunistring depedencies

Tags: guile

I'm trying to install meep and at the moment guile on my dir on a cluster. I'm not root.

guile needs libunistring. I have installed that but the ./configure of guile still can not find the libunistring. Of course I am telling it where to look at with

`--with-libunistring-prefix=/home/xxx/install/libunistring`

But I'm still receiving the same error.

```
    configure:21042: checking for libunistring
configure:21074: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  -lunistring >&5
conftest.c:141:21: error: uniconv.h: No such file or directory
```

and the uniconv.h is really where it should be.

Any input?

Comment: Which version of Guile are you using? I'll assume 2.0.11 unless you say otherwise.

Comment: Also, try using an absolute path for your `--with-libunistring-prefix`.

Comment: it is v 2.0.11. I'm using absolute path.

Comment: Please edit your question to use the _real_ path, since `dir/install/libunistring` is clearly not an absolute path. :-) (In troubleshooting situations, details matter. Don't edit them out.) Does the directory you specify contain an `include` and a `lib` directory? I just tested with `--with-libunistring-prefix=/usr/local/stow/libunistring-0.9.4` and, on my system, `/usr/local/stow/libunistring-0.9.4/include/uniconv.h` exists.

Comment: no the directory did not contain bin or includ. It turned out this particular issue was for gmp call `-- mpz_inits` that's what the cluster admin thinks. But I'm still dealing with other issues and posted another question.